# My laptop doesn't allow me to access the BIOS

Tags: ubuntu, bios

Although the instructions are "Press F2 to access bios / F4 for recovery" I don't get anything when I press those. Ubuntu starts automatically.
Then, if I press F10 I get the following screen, which is not what my BIOS used to look like:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: you may have a Fn button, try holding that button along with F2 to access bios, another alternative is to plug in an external keyboard and try F2 on that in case your F2 button is not working correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Check that your F2 and F4 keys work!!

http://www.keyboardtester.com/

Comment: Not that I think it's a great answer, but I feel you deserve an upvote for all the trouble you went through defending it.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Why thank you! in hindsight, it's a terrible answer, but helped me get a lot of clarification on how this site should be used, so in a funny way I learned as much from this answer as I did from a lot of other answers on this site!